# Advice on an efficient method to strip out color tags from LaTeX

Tags: lyx

I have revised a manuscript in LyX, and as requested by the journal editor, coloured the new text in red.

Once I completed the revision I exported to LaTeX to do the final tweaking of the manuscript.

I now have a revised manuscript in pdf format with all changes marked up in red text.

The problem is that I also need a unmarked up version (with red text removed).  I can remove the red coloring in the LyX file, but then need to re-export and re-tweak the entire document whenever I make a small change.

Because the color text was added in LyX I have `\textcolor{red}{Words and more words}` scattered all throughout the document.

Can someone give me a clue to an efficient way to strip out the `\textcolor{red}` tags and the corresponding `{}` throughout the Latex file?

I've tried searching online but have not managed to find an answer yet.

Comment: You could probably make `red` equivalent to `black`, or just make `\textcolor` a no-op (`\renewcommand{\textcolor}[2]{#2}`). However, that will still leave it in the code...

Comment: Welcome to the site! You could use something like [Most efficient method to strip all of the LaTeX code from a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102397)

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for that link. I don't think I will use that option now, but the perl script will come in very hand in the future

Comment: @Werner Thanks. This is probably going to be the easiest way to do this for the current document.  In the future I will make the most of Lyx's track changes function

Comment: Do you happen to be on Linux (or have a setup which allows for a regex to be run)? A simple `sed` command could do the trick, for example.

Comment: @scottkosty No, I'm on Windows. I'll have to look into it. Maybe GnuWin32 as an option, but I'm drifting into uncharted territory

Comment: @user2885462 yeah it sounds like you have both a short-term and long-term solution that work so no need to get fancy. But just remember that if a similar situation comes up and you are motivated to learn more, the term to search for is "regular expression". You can find/replace almost anything with it and many different programming languages and programs (e.g. Vim) have support for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does not solve your current problem (David's answer should work fine in this respect).

However, **next time** you need to highlight changes for your editor, remember that LyX has a pretty good built-in **change tracking system**: Just do your edits in change-tracking mode and you are done:

[image: Lyx with change tracking]

It's possible to have mark-ups for the changes in the PDF output, however, this is **optional**, so you could always also generate a plain PDF:

[image: PDF with change tracking]

Once you are finished, or if you editor has already approved some of your edits, you can make them "permanent" by *accepting* the respective change in LyX.

I have used this process in for a couple of journal and shepherded conference papers. The respective editors were always *extremely* happy with the highlighting

Comment: I had not thought that the track changes from LyX would carry over into the Latex code (stupid I know). I submit the raw Latex files, and the journal compiles them, but I suppose this is not a problem. Thanks so much! To late now, but very useful for the future!

Answer (score 18):

The option

```
\usepackage[monochrome]{color}
```

was designed for that use.

Comment: Thanks David, this will be helpful. This will leave the `\textcolor{}` code in which looks quite messy. Too late now, but lesson learned. I'll take Daniel's advice for editing future manuscripts.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can follow the following two steps to remove the annoying \textcolor{red}{} code in latex file: 1. Select all texts in the lyx file and right click the mouse, choose Text Style-->Customized-->Color-->Reset, then apply (This actually reset the font color to default). 2. Export the lyx file to latex file. You will see that there is no \textcolor{}{} command appearing in the latex file. I hope that this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: Of course it does. The only untrue  in this answer is the that the final step, at least in LyX 2.3.6 , is not "Reset" but "Default" or "(Without)". It is weird to have two options for the same, so I unsure if one could make something different in some context, but afaik, both just remove \textcolor. Without doubt this is the easiest solution of a LyX user to clean the LaTeX export, i.e., export it again in a version of LyX without colors.

Comment: Does it work when the coloring is done inside of math mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you upload your LaTeX file to Overleaf and enable `vim` keybindings, you can type

```
<Esc>
:s/\\textcolor\{red\}//g<Enter>
```

to remove all the `\\textcolor{red}`. I used Overleaf because I assume 'canonical' implies 'can be used irrespective of OS' and this doesn't require even Windows users to install anything extra. However, I can't quite figure out what variant of regular expressions Overleaf is using, so I couldn't match even the simplest of the corresponding `{}` pairs in Overleaf. However, with `sed` or the variant featured in Kile, for example, you should be able to remove most of those, too. In Kile, say, you could also review and approve each match prior to replacement.

Note that I tested this with a regular LaTeX file. I didn't test with LyX, so I'm assuming it spits out something reasonably standard.

This said, I'm honestly not sure this merits a canonical answer unless LyX is peculiarly dependent on this kind of appearance-based markup. The obvious (LaTeX) approach is to define a macro which you toggle between making its argument red and not doing so in the preamble. But perhaps that's hard to do in LyX. I'm also not sure what a 'canonical' answer means here.

Comment: *I'm also not sure what a 'canonical' answer means here.* I'm not sure either but I thought that was the best of the available options for what I want (which is simply an answer to this question!).

Comment: Unfortunately trying to export a very large LyX file to LaTeX, editing the LaTex, then trying to import it back to LyX usually causes a lot of bugs and headaches, so I don't think I'll try this.

Comment: @user24096 But the question was specifically how to remove the markup in the LaTeX document as opposed to the LyX version. So an answer to your question wouldn't answer this one. The OP explicitly says they could remove it in the LyX but don't want to.

Comment: OK my mistake, I will post another Q instead.