# How to (efficiently) remove colors in LyX?

Tags: color, lyx

Say I have a bunch of colors in math mode. How do I remove all of these colors (reset to default or black) efficiently?

[image]

(If the colors are in text i.e. not math mode, I can just do this: Select text > Text Style > Color > Default > Apply. But when the colors are in math mode, this doesn't work.)

[Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147114)

Answer (score 1):

A quick but dirty trick could be add to  <kbd>LaTeX Preamble</kbd> (in <kbd>Documents</kbd> → <kbd>Settings ...</kbd> → go to the bottom) this:

```
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0,0,0}
```

And so on with any other used color in math mode. Of course, this also will turn black `\texcolor{red}{foo}` in text mode.

Therefore, in case you want black maths but some red text elsewhere, you must turn "red" into black and another color into red.

In LaTeX this is not a problem because you can define custom names (e.g. "mathred", "textred", "funnycolor" ...) but you have seen that Lyx menu do not manage many of the predefined colors of `xcolor` but  only some basic colors, so you can only redefine the names of colors LyX knows about, except if you are OK using extensively ERT boxes with Ctrl-L to insert directly LateX code for custom colors names.

Otherwise, with the  menus you are limited to redefining basic colors that you really will never use (said  "orange", for example):

```
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0,0}
```

And then you can use the orange as an "exclusive red".

The MWE in latex could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\begin{document}
foo ${\color{red}foo}$  \textcolor{orange}{foo}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can also cut only "foo", leaving only  `{\color{red}}` that will be displayed as an empty blue box, then remove the box (not the math mode) and restore "foo", or for a long document, copy the entire code preview, paste it in a plain text editor,  clean all the  `\color{whatever}` manually, or by search & replace,  and then paste each formula (without the dollars) again in LyX after open the math mode (i.e, Ctrl+M, then Ctrl+V) that for a bunch of formulas, anyway will be a pain.